# How to install scripts for machine translation using Moses-For-Mere-Mortals on Linux (VirtualBox)

Tags: scripting, software-installation

I have installed VirtualBox on my computer, and Ubuntu by selecting Linux from the existing operating systems. When Ubuntu has started and I have downloaded Moses-For-Mere-Mortals from [github](https://github.com/jladcr/Moses-for-Mere-Mortals) .

After that I have tried to install by creating folders like this on desktop `desktop/machine-translation/moses-for-mere-mortals/scripts`. In this case i have renamed the file moses for mere mortals that i have downloaded from internet by deleting version number at the end.

There are 6 scripts in the scripts folder. From those I have installed the first one which is called "install" by using a command on the terminal. After this script finished/installed, at the 2nd step I tried to install "creating script" through terminal by copying its path and pasteing on terminal.

My question is here, that it has started to execute the file for installing and after some second it says error. I don't why it is not install and i can't solve this problem. How it can be solved?

Comment: Please include the complete text of any errors